# best way to ajax load-in external javascript files with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a one page web application, which means alot of javascript. External scripts like facebook connect etc most visitors wont use, so i'd like to know the BEST method of loading js files on an event (click, hover, timer etc). Idealy with jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery has [getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function.

> ```
> jQuery.getScript( url, [ success(data, textStatus) ] )
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Generate a `<script>` element, append it to `document.body`

Having one, single, minified, gzipped script probably isn't going to be that significant a bandwidth cost though.

Comment: some scripts i have to have separely as they're not hosted by me (like google analytics)

Comment: Are you really planning to load Google Analytics code on a conditional basis?!